# Xvfb -screen --> Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running

Tags: ubuntu, x-server, aws

I wonder, why isn't this working?

```
$ screen
$ Xvfb -screen :1 1024x768x16 &
[1] 17540
$ _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

And then after `Ctrl+C` or `+D` I run this:

```
$ ps -C Xorg
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

And, indeed, the X server isn't running. Why the error then?

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-123456-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

update:

[image]

Comment: please don't post images, copy the text. The above font messages are just warnings, unless you end up with no fonts at all. Are there any fatal messages beginning EE?

Comment: @meuh, it's more convenient for me to post images.

Comment: @アレックス so your convenience is more important than those who are taking valuable time out of their day to answer your question?

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you delete the following files before starting Xvfb as for ":1" screen:

```
rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
rm /tmp/.X1
```

Xvfb simply considers Xorg server running if it cannot create these "locking" files. This can be a case when another user created them on the same screen such as root, and you are starting Xvfb as a user that have no rights to delete the "locking" files. In other words Xvfb tries to delete and create "locking" files and if it fails it shows an error you've faced.

Comment: The OP really should have accepted this answer. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not work for me. OP's error only happens after I run the commands listed in this answer.

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary also sudo rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X0

Comment: What if those folders do not exist in the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: `rm /tmp/.X1-lock` maybe

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to run:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
```

where the `:1` is an argument on its own and means use the
default network connection +1, i.e. you will need to `export DISPLAY=:1` 
in the environment to connect to this display. Also, the X11 server
may run under the name `X` instead of `Xorg`.

Comment: thanks, but that led to other errors, please see my update.