# tigervncsesrver -> (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)

Tags: x11, xorg, tigervnc

When I try to start a Tiger VNC server with an SSH tunnel, I get the following error:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

To start it, I use the command `tigervncserver -localhost :1`. I have tried running `tigervncserver -kill :1`, but it says there is no VNC server. I have already removed the files `/tmp/.X1-lock` and `/tmp/.X11-unix/.X1`. It starts up when I use the command `tigervncserver -localhost :2`, but I want to use display :1

Using `netstat -lp | grep X1`, I see

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37348    2140/Xorg            @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4670129  951048/Xorg          /tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4670128  951048/Xorg          @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37349    2140/Xorg            /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

But when I try to kill the Xorg process 951048, another Xorg process is automatically created that uses `/tmp/.X11-unix/X1` and the same error appears.

I have already looked at these two questions, but they said to remove the files from `/tmp` which I have already done.

[Xvfb -screen --> Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232749/xvfb-screen-cannot-establish-any-listening-sockets-make-sure-an-x-server)

[Xvfb -screen --> (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314876/xvfb-screen-ee-cannot-establish-any-listening-sockets)

So my question is how do I fix this error and start a VNC server with display :1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I killed the `Xorg` process with the parameter `-core :0`, it killed all other `Xorg` process, then restarted automatically, and I was then able to use `tigervncserver` without issue.